# My android app not able to open directories to read files

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I have a app written in python/kivy that i have signed and installed on my android phone. The filemanager , an instance of the `MDFileManager` opens the root dir (/) and displays the file system. But i am not able to open any directory in internal or external storage, so that i can select a file. Most of the directories have a small lock icon on them and those dirs wont open. The directories without lock icon do not have any files or the type of files i want. I browsed the directory using a terminal app and found that the `ls` command on a locked directory returns a permission denied error. This happens only with this app. I am able to open directories and chose files with other 3rd party apps as well as my own app, written in react native. So not sure if this is an issue with `MDFIleManager` or something else. Any advise/workaround is highly appreciated

Comment: Chek if you have set proper permissions to access storage. Also if you have enabled the preview, only image files will be accessible.

Comment: Thanks. I just did that . The app had no permission to view storage on the phone. I enabled it and it works now. I could upvote if you answer this

Answer (score 1):

Viewing folders without accessing them is most likely due to not setting permissions. Add the following permissions in your manifest according to level of access:

- READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Yes. I also found that the these permissions allow the application itself be moved to external storage. By default apps are installed to internal storage and can not be moved